# Chrome MediaStreamTrack.getSources() returns sources with empty label

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, getusermedia

I used [simpl.info](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/) code as example. On their example I can see "TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD (13d3:5606)" in the "Video source" Select. Hence they can retrieve the label property of the sources.
I can get the sources easily but the label is empty:

```
SourceInfo {facing: "", label: "", kind: "video", id: "0c2c5a2bf359a3ced6d7d39efe2f40477f50d5627df618a6f1998b5142437b27"}
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    if (navigator.getUserMedia)
    {
        if (typeof MediaStreamTrack.getSources !== 'undefined')
        {
            MediaStreamTrack.getSources(gotSources);
        }
    }
});

function gotSources(sourceInfos)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++)
    {
        var sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];

        if (sourceInfo.kind == 'video')
        {
            console.log(sourceInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I bump into this too. In the documentation it is stated the label is empty if the user has not approved permissions to use his/hers camera / microphone, but for me the problem persist even if I have permissions. 

Can you try querying for the sources after you've been granted permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in [answer #4](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=267880), the user must have already granted permission to the page to use the media devices in order to get the `label` populated. When served over HTTPS, the browser will remember permission granted on subsequent loads, so the permission will have been granted before requesting media. When using HTTP, not HTTPS, the getUserMedia request must be made and accepted before `MediaStreamTrack.getSources` will populate labels.

I tried [simpl.info](https://simpl.info/getusermedia/sources/) on another computer and as expected the `label` was empty the first time, and populated after the second time.